# DoEvents() on WindowsPhone 8.1

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

im converting an VB .NET desktop code to run on windows phone 8.1.
in my MainPage.xml.vb i present an audio menu to a user over a text-to-speech engine.

after 1 menu item is read(), i need to give the user a certain time to react. in my desktop application i was able to use something like this:

```
Sub PresentMenuItem(mi as MyMenuItem)
  TTS.Speak(mi.Text)
  TimeoutTimer.Interval = 2000 'ms
  TimeoutTimer.Start()
  Do While TimeoutTimer.IsEnabled = true
    Application.DoEvents()
  Loop
End Sub
```

On windows phone there is no `DoEvents()` nor it seems to be clean programming. What kind of possibilities exists to solve this? Please help, thanks.

**Edit1**

More specific what i want to do:
i have a list of strings which i want to read to the user via text-to-speech. after the string[i.name] was read it looks for 1.5 seconds if a Gesture is drawn on the display. If drawn, the waiting process is stopped because the user made a selection. If after 1.5 seconds no gesture was drawn the waiting process stops as well. 
I am able to receive gestures drawn on the touchscreen but im totally stuck in how to do the waiting procedure correctly.

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    Friend Class MenuPage
        Friend Overrides Async Sub Provide() 
            Dim items = PageItems.Where(Function(c) c.Level = "1")
            Dim GIR As New GestureInputReceiver()

            For Each i In items
                Await TTS.Speak(i.Name)
                GIR.HookGestures(1500)

                'HERE i want to the app to have waited 1.5 seconds
                'and then be able to know the received Gesture, like:
                'Select Case GIR.LastGesture
                '  Case 0
                '    DoWhatever()
                'End Select
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class

    Friend Class GestureInputReceiver
        Dim WithEvents TimeoutTimer As New DispatcherTimer()
        Dim WithEvents GestureCheckerTimer As New DispatcherTimer()

        Public Sub New()
            GestureCheckerTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100)
        End Sub

        Friend Sub HookGestures(ms As Integer)
            TimeoutTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, ms)
            TimeoutTimer.Start()
            GestureCheckerTimer.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub TimeoutTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimeoutTimer.Tick
            If TimeoutTimer.IsEnabled = True Then
                GestureCheckerTimer.Stop()
                TimeoutTimer.Stop()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub GestureCheckerTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GestureCheckerTimer.Tick
            'if GestureReceived() = True Then ExitBothTimers() + SetLastGesture()
        End Sub
End Class
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks.

Comment: Any operation which takes any significant amount of time (more than a fraction of a second, basically) should be performed asynchronously and should not block the UI thread anyway.  There's no need for `DoEvents`.  Taking a step back (instead of trying to translate your old logic line by line), what are you doing which would block the UI?

Comment: basically there is no code which blocks the UI. But artificially i need to wait a few seconds on one line and then continue the code. as i understand ur reply i could start the timer on another thread, but how can i make my sub wait until the timer-thread has completed? thanks

Comment: "Wait a few seconds on one line and then continue the code" sure sounds like blocking the UI to me.  Why do you need to do this?  You're trying to block the UI thread, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: ok, yes right :). in the source snippet that i posted, the Tick_Handler is set to a procedure which checks if a gesture was drawn on the phones touchscreen. (have to admit i am total beginner on WP and just trying to port an old prog)

Comment: You *must* use the correct api on a Phone, the WinRT flavor.  When you do, you'll have very little trouble writing correct code, the SpeakTextAsync() method is easy to find.  [Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207057%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for the basics.

Comment: thanks hans, but i set up SpeakTextAsync() already. my problem is to wait additionaly some time after SpeakTextAsync_Completed().

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooope.  Phone apps are by nature asynchronous.  Dump your DoEvents nonsense and learn the joys of async/await.

Comment: any links/ideas on how to do this with async/await?